# Is there a possibility to Define authorization in accordingly to Session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've two Session Variable
Session var1 is a UserID
and Session var2 is a Type of User

Is there any other approach to provide privilege to a page according to Session var2 apart from inbuilt Role Classes and Inbuilt Membership option in visual Studio

Comment: You can implement role based authorization anyway you like, you don't need to use the built in framework, however, it sounds exactly like you want...

Comment: You should implement your custom membership provider not using session vars

Comment: If I use the custom membership provider then I have to change most of the codes., So is there any way by which i can authorize the session in the other webpages